# Run Rscript from shell

Tags: r, csh

I am trying to run multiple times an R script (Test.R) and a c script (speed.cxx) from the cshell

```
#!/bin/csh
@ x = 1
while ($x <= 2)
./speed && Rscript Test.R 
@ x ++
end
```

but it fails to load the libraries used in the R script

```
Loading required package: DBI
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/users/tito/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0/RPostgreSQL/libs/RPostgreSQL.so':
  libimf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RPostgreSQL’
Execution halted
```

To run this script I use `./test.csh`. On the other hand, if I run the R script outside the shell it works perfectly..

Comment: Is csh your default shell? Do you have environment variables set up to point to specific libraries on your machine? Try running an R script that just prints the `.libPaths()` both normally and via your csh script and compare the results.

Comment: `.cxx` is typically C++. It is not C. And none are scripting languages.

Comment: @MrFlick yes I get the same path